# Matlab -Neural Network Simulation (for Loop)

Tags: matlab, loops, neural-network

I am quiet new to matlab NN toolbox and have created the following NN network:

```
val.P=Exp;

net =newff(minmax(p),[20,3],{'tansig','purelin'},'trainlm');

net.trainParam.epochs = 5000;    %Max Ephocs
net.trainParam.goal = 1e-5;     %Training Goal in Mean Sqared Error
net.trainParam.min_grad = 0.05e-3;
net.trainParam.show = 50;       %# of ephocs in display
net.trainParam.max_fail =20;
net = init(net);

[net,tr]=train(net,p,t,[],[],val);
o1 = sim(net,Exp)
```

How can I run the above for say 20 times and store the data in one variable (o1)?
Any help is very much appreciated !

Comment: Hi, Please see the revised question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for iteration=1:20
  % Your NN code
  [net, tr]=train(net,p,t,[],[],val);
  o1(:,iteration) = sim(net,Exp);
end
```

After that, `o1` will be an array with all the results in it.

Note: Since I don't know the dimensions of your data, you might need to modify o1(iteration) to o1(:,iteration) or o1(:,:,iteration) etc. Whatever you need.

Comment: Thanks alot for the reply, but matlab gives the following error:???  o1[iteration] = sim(net,Exp);
       |
Error: Unbalanced or
unexpected parenthesis or
bracket.

Comment: o1 is <3x1> after 20 iteration I want matlab to give me a <3x20> o1. I tried  o1(iteration,:) = sim(net,Exp); and this is what matlab gives me ??? Subscripted assignment
dimension mismatch.

Comment: Exactly what I was going to answer. Personally I would go for o1(:, iteration), that way something like sum(o1 - TestData) will give you a result for each experiment. Also o1(:,:,iteration) etc just makes more sense to me...

Comment: without the loop what does this give you: o1 = sim(net,Exp); size(o1)?

Comment: @Jia: Thank you so much.  o1(:, iteration) Solved the problem.

Comment: Glad it was helpful, I edited the answer to the final solution

Comment: @Dan: Without the loop the size is:  o1 <3x1>