# how to use saved neural network(training) in a loop while testing in another loop

Tags: matlab, neural-network

[Matlab -Neural Network Simulation (for Loop)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10534219/matlab-neural-network-simulation-for-loop/29361912#29361912)

Thanks for your above answer using for loop. Now I want to save the trained network (which has been trained using 2 different input images(type 1 and type 2) and different target images(type 1 and type 2) ), after saving network I need to test the network for different images to classify them, whether they belongs to type 1 or type 2.

Please guide me how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve the network and put it in your workspace with:

```
load net; %
```

If you want to get predictions use:

```
perform(net,y)
```

I would suggest you run the network on a similar image matrix you used during training.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but while testing i am getting type 1 image only even after using type2 images which i used while training.  i want to know how to use the saved net.mat by splitting it into two classes and using it for classification ..is there any chose to do that.. i am working on'false positive reduction in computer-aided diagnostic scheme for detecting nodules in chest radiographs by means of massive training artificial neural network'

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your saying. If your output layer is two neurons (as it should be in a two category classification), then you can simply take the neuron with the bigger value. Any data you pass in will make cause one of the neurons to be bigger, and therefore classify the data into two categories. If you want more categories, simply add more neurons on the output layer.

Comment: i am taking 2 images pre prossesed them part of code is given blow F=dir('trainimgs');
F=char(F.name);
for ii=1:2
    str=F(ii+2,:);
cd trainimgs
I=imread(str);          
JJ=imfinfo(str);
cd ..
JC=JJ.Comment;           D=zeros([56 56]);
D(21:37,21:37)=1;
w= fspecial('gaussian',16,16);
L1=imfilter(D,w); 
L2=zeros([56 56]);
if strcmp(JC,'nodule')==1
    
idf=L1;
else   
    idf=L2;
end

Comment: ak=9;bk=9;k=1;
for ll=1:size(b,1)-8
    for jj=1:size(b,2)-8
        blk=b(ll:ak,jj:bk);
        net = newff(blk(:),idf(k),20,{'tansig','logsig'},'trainrp');
        [net,tr]=train(net,blk(:),idf(k));
       % y=sim(net,blk(:));
        Y(ii,k)=y;
        k=k+1;
       bk=bk+1;
       %clear N
    end
    ak=ak+1;
    bk=9;
end
save('net.mat','net');
end

Comment: now testing part.... [J P]=uigetfile('.jpg','select a file for testing ');  load('net.mat');
ak=9;bk=9;k=1;
for mm=1:size(b1,1)-8
    for nn=1:size(b1,2)-8
        blk1=b1(mm:ak,nn:bk);
        DF=repmat(blk1(:),[1 2])';
        y1=sim(net,blk1(:));
        Y1(k)=y1;
        k=k+1;
       bk=bk+1;
    end
    ak=ak+1;
    bk=9;
end
T=reshape(Y1(:),[56 56]);
figure;
imshow(T);  now i am getting 1 classification only for all images i.e L2 what i did wrong while testing or training please help me sir

Comment: now i need to get an image like target 1(L1) or target2(L2) based on classification..